# Shared Preference shows null value when the app rerun after crash

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I used sharedPreference to save my object and it works fine but the problem is when the app is crashed it try to run Previous activity in which I call this getQbUser() method shared Preference couldn't find any object any start crashing in loop until I closed the app and rerun my application and it works fine.Shared Preference has the object.

```
public void saveQbuser(QBUser user){
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPref.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(user);
    prefsEditor.putString("qbuser", json);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}

public QBUser getQbUser(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = mPref.getString("qbuser","");
    QBUser obj = gson.fromJson(json, QBUser.class);
    return obj;

}
```

//Logs

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    com.attribes.push2beat.Utils.DevicePreferences.getQbUser (DevicePreferences.java:86)
    com.attribes.push2beat.mainnavigation.SelectActivity.createChatService (SelectActivity.java:38)
    com.attribes.push2beat.mainnavigation.SelectActivity.onCreate (SelectActivity.java:27)
    android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6251)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1107)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2369)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2476)
    android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1344)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
    android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Note : The Problem is occur only when the app is crash state and try to run previous activity by itself otherwise there is no issue in my Preference class  **

Comment: where did you initialise "mPref" object???? Please post full code..

Comment: did u initialized ur `SharedPreferences mPref;`  ?

Comment: your sharedPref variable if you have initialised will be null after app crash

Comment: /data/data/your.app.id/shared_prefs/your.app.id_preferences.xml / -  check your shared-preferences file in DDMS

Comment: Your _mPref_ is null

Comment: @Avinashkumawat I didn't post full class the preference is working fine throughout the app and save the object and retrieve it without any problem but when the app is crashed my android device is run the previous activity automatically and on that time it didn't found any value. But if you closed the app and run again that activity Preference has that object

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show your QBUser.class

I think your QBUser class should be like this.

```
public class QBUser {

@SerializedName("name")
String name;

@SerializedName("address")
String address;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

You need to add SerialzedName Annonation for converting object to string
Your code does not able to convert object to string thats why you getting this error.

For Other people who does'nt know this things please keep it mind.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but not able to comment.

Comment: Its require 50 reputation, please focus on question not this shit

Comment: Now i think it would be fine MR. DOVYDAS SOPA

Comment: @divyanshingle It is QuicBlox api class. so I can't edit it.

Comment: So you can not able to save it directly using Gson lib because you have to create your own lass and add annotation on variable then it will become JSON string and then shared preference will able to save it as a string. I suggest you create your own class and set variable then you will able to save it on preference

Answer (score 0):

U can follow this code:

String PREFS_NAME="QBUser";

```
 public void saveQbuser(Context context,QBUser user) {
    Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(user);
        prefsEditor.putString("qbuser", json);
        prefsEditor.commit();

}
public QBUser getQbUser()
{

 SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = preferences.getString("qbuser","");
QBUser obj = gson.fromJson(json, QBUser.class);
return obj;

}
```

or your QBUser.class

```
public class QBUser
   {
   // do here code setter or getter method of jsonString or objects.
      }
```

Comment: I didn't post full class the preference is working fine throughout the app and save the object and retrieve it without any problem but when the app is crashed my android device is run the previous activity automatically and on that time it didn't found any value. But if you closed the app and run again that activity Preference has that object

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
 class PrefsHelper{


    private SharedPreference mPref;
    private Editor edit;
    private static final PREFS_NAME = "myprefs";


    public PrefsHelper(Context context){
     mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit = mPref.edit();
    }

     public void saveQbuser(QBUser user)
        {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(user);
            edit.putString("qbuser", json);
            edit.commit();

    }


public QBUser getQbUser()
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = mPref.getString("qbuser","");
    QBUser obj = gson.fromJson(json, QBUser.class);
    return obj;

}
    }
```

Comment: I didn't post full class the preference class is working fine throughout the app and save the object and retrieve it without any problem but when the app is crashed my android device is run the previous activity automatically and on that time it didn't found any value. But if you closed the app and run again that activity Preference has that object

Comment: Can you show me the code of your activity to which your app return when app crashes??

Comment: I think you don't find value on your previous activity when app crashes because you must have shown the object in the super method  like in onCreate() which is not called. When your app crashes your previous activity calls onResume() because it was never destroyed.

Comment: I called it in onCreate() and that's why the app is crashing.The problem is .onCreate trigger everytime but can't able to find device data on crash state.